# Ubuntu free for Desktop?

Tags: license

Can I use Desktop version of Ubuntu linux in my office environment, I do not need any extended support for my desktops.

Comment: In short, Yes you can.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use it for free.

However, why not consider a donation to Ubuntu project if your company is using it and making money? A fraction of what you would pay for Windows for example? Or buy a support, that way you have dedicated people at Canonical to look after you.

Comment: Thanks, this helps.